# Adding SSL certificates to Amazon AWS - S3 and AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-certificate-manager

I am using Amazon AWS as a back-end for my application development. I am mainly using the 2 resources of AWS -

1. S3 bucket storage
2. AppSync (With DynamoDB as Data Source)

I want to use or 'apply' SSL certificates for security on above 2 resources. I know I can create certificate from AWS Certificate Manager.

The problem is the documention mentions that certificates can only be applied to the below 6 resources:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html

1. Load Balancer
2. CloudFront
3. Elastic Beanstalk
4. API Gateway
5. Cloud Formation
6. Nitro Enclaves

I have already mentioned that I am using S3 and AppSync. These 2 resources are not in the above list. How do I apply certificates on the 2 resources - S3 and AppSync ?

Do I need to do some kind of workaround ?

Comment: How are you planning to use S3 & AppSync? I mean s3 itself won't need ssl but when it has static website hosting the ssl will be needed for CloudFront distribution to redirect requests from HTTP to HTTPS. same way for AppSync for the appsync apis.

Comment: @kru . Actually I am not doing anything related to web content. My application is not a web-site. My front-end client is a mobile app. This front-end mobile app uploads pics which is collected in `s3`. Also I am maintaining `AppSync (DynamoDB database)` for maintaining records of the pics uploaded and which pic belongs to which user and more. Therefore I am using only `s3` and `AppSync` - only these 2 services for my mobile app. I want to attach my self-created SSL certificate to s3 and/or AppSync.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an AppSync api with the graphql (something like: `https://abc.appsync.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql`) and mention that api endpoint as the origin in cloudfront distribution.

Please check this blog from AWS which explains better for AWS AppSync :
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-a-custom-domain-with-aws-appsync-amazon-cloudfront-and-amazon-route-53/